# Using block to navigate to several links (with Mechanize)

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I keep getting the following output when running this block. It's like the 'user' link (which shows fine in a puts statement) isn't being translated into the correct link in the links_with method:

https://www.reddit.com/r/aww/#content

It should be linking to the user's profile page (ie /username instead of #content).

```
require 'mechanize'

mechanize = Mechanize.new

page = mechanize.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/aww/')

page.xpath('//*[contains(@class,"tagline")]/a[contains(@href,"user/")]/@href').each do |user|
    puts user
    new_page = page.link_with(user).click
    puts new_page.uri
end
```

Comment: do you need to click? couldn't you just do `new_page = mechanize.get(user)`?

Comment: ultimately, I need to navigate to the user's profile page. does 'get' do the same thing?

Comment: yes. click would just set the referer, but you can set that manually for get if the page would block you for not looking like a real user.

Comment: Great - I'll give that a shot later today

Comment: i tried it with your code myself and it seems to work on reddit. however, if you're actually using it for reddit, that data is also available through the reddit API and there's a ruby wrapper for that in https://github.com/avinashbot/redd

Comment: thank you - trying to create my own for practice